# Malware static rules?

Tags: malware, static-analysis

Is there any sites to get static rules to detect malware files?
static behavior rules for detecting malware files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/Yara-Rules/rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create or download tools to scan files with YARA rules. There are many repositories on github with custom rules and you can also get the ClamAV database, which is all in YARA. I think Kaspersky's database is also available in YARA rules. You can also use Loki; a fine tool for incident response which does this job and many more!